# Use what private c++ function return type for hooking using mobilesubstrate

Tags: iphone, c++, hook, jailbreak

I am examining the private c++ function hooking code snippet from [mobilesubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) and see that the WebCore example seems to be hooking onto 2 (possibly) undocumented private functions mangled and buried in WebCore. What strikes me is how saurik deduces the type of return value the target hook function returns??? A mangled function does not leak return type from what I know. I tried disassembling the WebCore framework shared library file in IDA pro and could not see its return type. Any idea anyone? Is full knowledge required of the target function prototype and return type required to successfully hook onto private functions in dylibs?? Thanks!

```
#define WebKit "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit"
#define WebCore "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore"
//how to tell its an NSURLRequest* ?
NSURLRequest* (*X_ZNK7WebCore15ResourceRequest12nsURLRequestEv)(void* something);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you do not need to know the exact return type, for example I was able to hook successfully:

```
static FILE * close(int arg1),
```

although close() returns void

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but i tried compiling the example in the mobilesubstrate topic on iphonedevwiki for a simple mobilesafari tweak and produced a workable tweak. However, when I changed the return type of `NSURLRequest* (*X_ZNK7WebCore15ResourceRequest12nsURLRequestEv)(void* something);
` from void to int, i get `Tweak.xm:67: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(void*, void*, long unsigned int, void*, const void**)’ to ‘void*’` is because of MSHake?